# Kind of inverse Stolz theorem

Tags: limits

Let's suppose we have two series $(a_n), (b_n)$, such that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$$

It would seem intuitive that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - b_n)  = 0 $$

Is this hypothesis true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false, consider $a_n=n$ and $b_n=n+1.$ Then
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=-1\underset{n\to\infty}{\not\to}0.$

Comment: Similarly, for $a_n = 2n^2 + n, b_n = 2n^2$ we see that $(a_n - b_n)$ may not converge at all

Answer (score 0):

Let $(c_n)$ be an **arbitrary** sequence. If $(b_n)$ is a fast enough growing sequence, and $a_n=b_n+c_n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ and $a_n-b_n=c_n$.